# Перезапись объекта в файле

Tags: android, serialize

Есть файл в котором храниться список объектов( одним объектом "Список")  либо просто N-ое количество объектов. Возможно ли каким то образом брать из файла - конкретный объект и производить над ним "GRUD" операции ?

```
public class Serialization {
    private static final String TAG = "MySerialization";
    Context context;

    public Serialization(MainActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }


public void serializationList(ContactList contactList) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = context.openFileOutput("ContactList.ser", 0);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(contactList);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
}

 public void deserializationList() {
        ContactList contactList;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput("ContactList.ser");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            contactList = (ContactList) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("ContactList class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
}


    public void serialization(Contact contact) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fileOut = context.openFileOutput("contact.ser", 0);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(contact);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        Log.d(TAG,"Serialized data is saved in contact.ser");

        deserialization();
    }

    public void deserialization(){

        ContactCaling e;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = context.openFileInput("contact.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            e = (Contact) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Contact class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: читайте весь список, проводите операции над обним объектом, записывайте список обратно. Это вообще-то задача как раз для базы данных. Выборка из сериализованного списка намного сложнее

Comment: @metalurgus ясно, спасибо!